# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) / Web API / OAuth / OpenID / Tokens / Cookies / What do I really need?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, token, asp.net-core

I have an existing project that I am looking to migrate to ASP.NET 5.

Currently it is a simple ASP.NET Web Forms project that references 2 DLLs:

- Domain.dll that contains all the business logic
- Data.dll that contains all the data access code

Normally I shouldn't have to touch those 2 DLLs which are currently working fine.
Now I'd like to replace the ASP.NET Web Forms project by 2 new components:

- A front-end SPA with angular2
- A Web API back-end with ASP.NET 5 (vNext)

I've been playing with the templates available in VS2015, I've also been reading everything I could about authentication and I must say, I am now getting even more confused as to what I really need... :(

Do I need MVC in my back-end API? All the examples are done with ASP.NET MVC, but if I have a fully working SPA front-end, Don't I just need a simple RESTful service?

What do I need for authentication? Do I need ASP.NET Identity? Is Identity the new version of the old Membership? Does it take care of the creation of tokens? I already have a production database with all my users and hashed passwords. My Domain.dll assembly also has all the necessary code for validating users credentials.

What do I need if I want to allow other login services like Google or Facebook? I've created some web applications using both, ASP.NET 4.5 and ASP.NET 5 templates, to see how things are done, but that's where confusion got worse. ASP.NET 4.5 template uses Owin stuff (which I'm not familiar with), and ASP.NET 5 template doesn't.

Ideally here's what I'd really want: I'd like to create a Web API project with the minimum amount of dependencies, I'd like to avoid using sessions and cookies and I'd like to be able to use Google's and Facebook's services for logging in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll say that... it sounds like a full rewrite.

Let's go over your points...

#### Do I need MVC in my back-end API?

In `ASP.NET 5` we don't *really* have MVC and WebAPI anymore. They are both very similar in concepts and have been merged. It's all about what you return. If you return an `IActionResult`, it will kick in the Razor and ViewEngines. If you return an object, then it will try to serialize your object based on HTTP Headers (what WebApi does).

#### Don't I just need a simple RESTful service?

If you have a full front-end SPA app with Angular? Yep. That's all you need and this whole MVC thing is not mandatory. You just need to create a web api. Microsoft have a nice [tutorial right here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) on how to do it.

#### What do I need for authentication?

I would highly recommend an SSO. This mitigate the need to re-implement the authentication yourself. If you are more of a public application, try to support Facebook/Twitter/Google. If it's a business application, [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) can do the job but at that point, it's specific to what your client have so... it might not be the best solution.

#### Do I need ASP.NET Identity?

No but for ASP.NET 5/MVC6, it's the only one that exist right now so for the moment? Yes you do but the whole ASP.NET system is made to be replaceable at every place in the system. Identity does not use the older membership system. It uses claims and that's a whole different subject.

Identity will take care of everything you need to authenticate every request (tokens and more). The good news? It supports Facebook, Google and many others.

#### More info here

Basically, `ASP.NET 5` is a huge pipeline with dependency injection as a first class citizen. Adding element to the pipeline makes them available to those later in the pipeline.

This pipeline is configured in `Startup.cs` and is separated in 2 steps. `ConfigureServices` which is where the dependency injection is configured and `Configure` where the actual elements of the pipeline are added. Want to replace the default logger? ConfigureServices. Want to add an element in the pipeline? Configure.

That's it really!

#### Recommended reading:

- [Migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 app to ASP.NET 5](https://weblogs.asp.net/paullitwin/migrating-an-asp-net-mvc-5-app-to-asp-net-5)
- [The State of Security in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6: Claims & Authentication](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/21/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-claims-authentication/)
- [The State of Security in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6: OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect and IdentityServer](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/22/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-and-identityserver/)

Comment: Merci! I didn't realise ASP.NET 5 was such a big step.

Comment: ASP.NET 5 is a huge step. But it brings so much. It's basically future proof to any future protocol change since everything is handled with another element in the pipeline. It's also very efficient since you only add what you need. Add that it's also cross-platform (with `dnxcore50`) and you suddenly have something amazing. :) Ce fût un plaisir. ;-)

Comment: If you compare it to the old way, the pipeline was already there for you and you only had one way to run it. IIS. Now you can run it anywhere, including self-hosting it yourself. They couldn't port WebForms but they managed to bring MVC with it. Do not hesitate to ask other questions!

Comment: do you know of any example or tutorial using mvc6 api with Identity? You mentioned it could take care of tokens. When I create an asp.net 5 api web project with vs 2015 it does not provide any authentication options like the other project template does. Is there maybe a SPA example anywhere that shows authentication with identity?

Comment: Are you talking about tokens that would be sent to a web api and would need to be validated against a central authority? :)

Comment: Thanks for all this precious information. Now I know I should first read about asp.net 5 before going any further. I come from the old times and thought I wouldn't need to concentrate on this, big mistake ;)

Comment: Now that I know more about ASP.NET 5, I was able to reference my existing assemblies, and have my own context resolved and instantiated using the following line in my Startup.ConfigureServices: services.AddSingleton<Domain.Contracts.IDataContext, Data.Context>();
Of course I had to tweak my Configuration object that was still based on System.Configuration, but now my controllers can have my own context as constructor parameter. It's brilliant!
Encore merci Maxime for simply not throwing anything like "Have you done any research yourself?" ;)

Comment: My pleasure Seb. More than the job of the Microsoft MVPs to be there for the community. It's our pleasure.  :-)